# NSInternalInconsistencyException' 'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE should be used in NPOT dimensions'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d, nsassert

I just upgraded my project from Kobold2d 1.1.2 to 2.0.4 and now every time I try to build I get this message.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[CCTexture2D setTexParameters:], /Desktop Items/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m:856
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE should be used in NPOT dimensions'
```

I know that it is basicly telling my that my images are not a power of 2, but there is the same NSASERT in the older version of kobold2d and everything passes just fine.

Comment: 90% of the images in my project are not a power of 2.

Comment: hmmm maybe you need to enable NPOT support in ccConfig.h

Comment: Where do I do that at? I don't see any option to enable NPOT support in the ccConfig.h.

Comment: I could really use some help with this!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  Where do I do that at? I don't see any option to enable NPOT support in the ccConfig.h.

Comment: @Stephen if you find the answer ,please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

The magic words are:

```
CCConfiguration.m:
// around line 122  
supportsNPOT_ = NO; // before it said YES
```